# How do I configure LVDS+DisplayPort+DisplayPort using an Nvidia chipset?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

I have a Thinkpad T520 with Nvidia Optimus. For my own sanity, I've set it (in the BIOS) to use 100% discrete graphics, so the Intel graphics are never used. There are 3 displays: The laptop's built in LCD, plus two DVI connections via a port replicator.

The problem is, when I use either the built-in monitor configuration tools, or nvidia-settings to configure my display, I'm not able to get all 3 displays to show up. Nvida-settings specifically gives me this message:

MetaMode 1 of Screen 0 has more than 2 active display devices.

[image: Screenshot of Nvidia-settings error]

I'm not sure what that means. This is with an Nvidia GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1), per lspci:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 21cf
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 6000 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at f3080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

EDIT: Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +   50.0  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 290mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DP-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Another edit. This is the result of trying to use xrandr (via arandr):

```
$ xrandr --output VGA-0 --off --output LVDS-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-5 --off --output DP-4 --off --output DP-3 --off --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x0 --rotate normal --output DP-0 --off
xrandr: cannot find crtc for output LVDS-0
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?s=a194d50117d730467f80a32b1be9e74b&t=72490 it may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wait I look now - no it is a simple *.run - package - here is the location:

http://www.nvidia.de/object/cuda_1_1_beta.html

But this package makes a big difference than to those encluded elder packages of nvidia
for case you have optimus CUDA cards.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of optimus-CUDA strongly depends on this new 
package (since May) of nvidia:

NVIDIA_CUDA_SDK_1.1_Beta_Linux.run

Do you have installed it ? - It makes a big difference.

Comment: Can you tell us where to go to download this run file please.

Comment: Is this a Debian package?